# where to put orderby in linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

Here is my code and i want to order by via date_added column. i tried all the possibilities but still the date_added column sorted via month instead of a year. Please guide where i need to put orderby statement.further the date_added return result in string datatype.

```
  {
            var records = (from r in db2.documents
                           select new
                           {
                               r.show_in_portal,
                               r.buyer_id,
                               r.advertiser_id,
                               r.contract_id,
                               r.campaign_id,
                               date_added = Dates.FormatDateToExt(r.date_added),
                               id = r.document_id,
                               name = r.filename,
                               location = r.filename,
                               r.publisher_id,
                               affiliate_id = (r.contract != null ? r.contract.publisher_id : -1),
                               document_type = r.document_type.type_name
                           });
            if (campaign_id > 0)
                records = records.Where(v => v.campaign_id == campaign_id);
            //if (creativeid > 0)
            //  records = records.Where(v => v.id == creativeid);
            if (affid > 0)
                records = records.Where(v => v.publisher_id == affid);
            if (contid > 0)
                records = records.Where(v => v.contract_id == contid);
            if (advertiserid > 0)
                records = records.Where(v => v.advertiser_id == advertiserid);
            if (buyerid > 0)
                records = records.Where(v => v.buyer_id == buyerid);

            GridOut(context, records.ToArray());
        }

public static string FormatDateToExt(DateTime? input)
{
    return FormatDateToExt(input, 0);
}

public static string FormatDateToExt(DateTime? input, int time_offset = 0)
{
    return input != null ? input.Value.AddHours(-1 * time_offset).ToString("MM/dd/yyy h:mm:ss tt") : "";
}
```

Comment: "i tried all the possibilities" like what? Have you tried after all the If statements?

Comment: What data type is `date_added`? `DateTime`? `string`?

Comment: Please post the full definition of `Dates.FormatDateToExt`

Comment: I suspect that your problem is that your Dates.FormatDateToExt() function is converting a true date/time value into some text presentation that is no longer sortable (like "2/4/2022" or "04 Feb 22"). You need to sort using the original value. Adding a sort before the  anonymous type creation may cause performance problems (all data retrieved and sorted before filters applied). I suggest that you reorder your code to (1) access db2.documents as a IQueryable, (2) apply filters, (3) apply the date_added sort (while it is still a date/time type), (4) map to your anonymous type.

Comment: i added the FormatDateToExt function above to make it more clear, further the output is on string of date_added . moreover im getting the sorting via string base instead of date bases like year.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your query is a sequence of some anonymous type. `Date_Added` is one of the properties of this anonymous type, so after you created your query you can order by `Date_Added`.

The type of `Date_Added` is the returned type of `Dates.FormatDateToExt(...)`. Alas you forgot to inform us about this type. Is it a DateTime? Is it a string? If you order by this type do you get the sorting order that you want?

If so, just add the OrderBy at the end:

```
var records = db2.documents.Select(document => new
{
    Id = document.document_id,

    Portal = document.Show,
    BuyerId = document.buyer_id,
    AdvertiserId = document.advertiser_id,
    ...
    DateAdded = Dates.FormatDateToExt(document.date_added),
});

if (campaign_id > 0)
    records = records.Where(record => record.campaign_id == campaign_id);
if (affid > 0)
    records = records.Where(record => record.publisher_id == affid);
... // etc. other ifs and other wheres

records = records.OrderBy(record => record.DateAdded);
```

It is a good thing to do the Sorting at the end, because this means that you will have to sort fewer records. All records that don't pass all Wheres, won't have to be sorted.

Finally a small hint: did you see, that if you use proper identifiers, that your queries will be easier to read? It is good practice to use plural nouns for collections of items, and singular nouns for elements of the collection:

```
var novels = dbContext.Books.Where(book => book.Type == BookType.Novel)
```

Comment: Hi Harald, Thanks for your help. 
 I edit the code part and add the function FormatDatetoExt. Further the return of date_added is in string data type. when i add the orderby as per ur provided help, it stuck the page . 
actually its order by it as a string and i want it to orderby as datetime from year instead of a month.

Comment: So do the OrderBy when the type is still a DateTime. Alternative: Select also the date as a DateTime, and do the OrderBy there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your dates uniform by using ISO 8601 ones (convert them on the fly in your Linq query), as they're made to be sortable.
You can put the `orderby` clause after the `from`.

Read:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/working-with-datetime-using-C-Sharp/
- https://dev.to/adnauseum/sorting-iso-8601-timestamps-5am2